# scrolling image wall with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I need some help figuring out how I should do this.

I would like to make a scrolling image wall with jQuery. I just want to tile hundreds of small images (twitter profile pics) and just have them tiled one after another in the browser window. This tiling should space the whole width/height of the browser window. Basically I want to make a page with javascript where you enter a user's twitter name, it makes a call to the API, and it returns the profile pics of all the user's followers. These pictures are then placed into the previously mentioned full-page scrolling image wall. The images should wrap, when they scroll off the page to the right they wrap around on the left.

Does anyone know how I would do this? What library would I use? Any help / direction pointing is much appreciated!

Thank you

EDIT: 
To clarify; I already know how to retrieve the images (that's as far as I've gotten) however I don't know how to lay them out in a full-screen tile form, and have them scroll left-to-right (so if there are more friends/images than can fit on the screen). How hard would that part be? Are there any good libraries for scrolling/wrapping images around a browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use the Twitter API to get the followers [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids)

Then you can use the [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) to get the images for each user (bit painful I know, but I can't see any other way around it).

After that, you'd print the results on a page, with each result being floated left. If you search up floated elements and how they work, you'll see that displaying the results like you describe is trivial.

If you have any specific issues with any of these tasks, don't hesitate to post a more detailed question.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the input -- I already know how to retrieve the images (that's as far as I've gotten) however I don't know how to lay them out in a full-screen tile form, and have them scroll left-to-right (so if there are more friends/images than can fit on the screen). How hard would that part be? Are there any good libraries for scrolling/wrapping images around a browser window?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - you don't need any specific libraries for wrapping elements, it's just css `float`. I've created a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrjEy/). Is this what you're envisioning?

Comment: you have the tiling correct, but I want the images to animate from one side of the screen to the other, like a slider or image carousel, not a manual scroll bar. I don't know how else to explain it; I know this is possible with javascript but I can't readily find examples. Think like a marquee, but with tiled images.

Comment: Yes just like that, except taking up the whole width and height of the browser window, and instead of just having the images one after another, they're tiled in a grid, and the whole grid of images scrolls like in simplyscroll.